# Kinetic js mousemove set attrs

Tags: kineticjs, mousemove, setattribute

I want to move a shadow on mousemove when I mousemove over an area. It works with a click and tween but not on mousemove. I guess I have to update the stage because if something different on stage is tweened it works for a short while till the other tween is finished.
Please help and thanks in advance.

```
greyBack.on('mousemove', function() {
  var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
  var x = (mousePos.x) -  (stage.getWidth());
  var y = (mousePos.y) -  (stage.getHeight());

  shadow1.setAttrs({
    x: [x*(-1)],
    y: [y*(-1)],
  })                                                   
});
```

Comment: I think you should be using `shadow1.setPosition(x,y)` instead of `setAttrs`. Also, not sure where the tween comes into play here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to call `layer.drawScene()` or `stage.draw()` to update the canvas. On `click` and during tweens it gets called automatically.

Your modified code would look like that:

```
greyBack.on('mousemove', function() {
  var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
  var x = (mousePos.x) -  (stage.getWidth());
  var y = (mousePos.y) -  (stage.getHeight());

  shadow1.setAttrs({
    x: [x*(-1)],
    y: [y*(-1)],
  })     
  layer.drawScene(); //Or stage.draw(); - I don't know how you grouped your shapes ;)                                        
});
```

Comment: Since you found this useful, you might be kind and select it with the checkmark so that we know it's already answered.